# Apache httpd: cache miss: cache unwilling to store response

Tags: apache

I've been trying to configure my Apache Httpd 2.4 server to use mod_cache and mod_cache_disk to do caching for a Wordpress site. It should have a big improvement of performance. I have followed all the guides and done everything right, and yet... no files get saved in the cache.

I enabled logging of cache errors and I see this error coming up: "cache miss: cache unwilling to store response". Ok... I looked in the source code of mod_cache.c and it looks like that happens when cache_create_entity() returns anything other than OK. So I looked at the souce of mod_ccache_disk.c and I can see that in create_entity(), it silently fails if conf->cache_root == NULL. In all other cases, it would log an error or return OK.

I can only assume that it's failing because conf->cache_root is null. Where does that come from? It would come from ap_get_module_config to get the config of the cache_disk_module.

How can that possibly be returning null? And more annoyingly, why does the Apache server give some log message when there's a major error condition, such as loading a module but not having a config object for it?

Really stumped on this one... Thank you.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_cache_disk.html#cacheroot

Comment: That's already in there. I definitely had that. And yet somehow the server processes the configuration but ignores that parameter, and does so without giving any error messages.

Comment: The docs do say "Failing to provide a value for CacheRoot will result in a configuration file processing error" so maybe this isn't what's happening?

Comment: Are you sure your server is sending cacheable responses? Did you try setting CacheDetailHeader?

Comment: It's definitely trying to cache them. I set the detail header and I get: X-Cache-Detail: "cache miss: attempting entity save" which is what also showed up in the logs. It's weird, there's no configuration file processing error. Apache starts with no complaints. But it's obviously in a non-valid condition with CacheRoot not being set. Crazy. I'm looking through source code and I just don't see how this happens, no one else is getting this, and somehow I'm getting it to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: SELinux was blocking files from being created in the CacheRoot I specified. I had to put it in the right directory that had permissions, or I could have added permission to the directory.